# Resources for learning about NoSql/Non relational databases

Tags: nosql, hadoop, cassandra, non-relational-database

Are there any good resources and/or sample applications(in C# preferably, but any will do) for learning more about designing applications around non-relational databases such as <strike>hadoop</strike>, cassandra, etc?

I am more interested in learning the design/theory of such applications as opposed to learning about specific non-relational db products.

Thus far, my development experience has been centered around relational data models and I am interested in learning about the use of non-relational models in place/along side of relational databases.

I am definitely a beginner in this area so I need to start from the ground up here...

Comment: hadoop is not a database

Comment: oops dont know how I let that slip by me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cassandra article and presentations](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArticlesAndPresentations)

[Cassandra + hadoop](http://www.slideshare.net/jeromatron/intro-to-cassandra-hadoop-5314244)

[Cassandra data modelling](http://www.slideshare.net/gdusbabek/data-modeling-with-cassandra-column-families)

[Cassandra data model](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel)